# Passing variables from function to function

Tags: python

I have a question about passing variables from function to another function by using this code:

```
def Hello():
    good = "Nice"
    return good

def Bye():
    print (good)

Hello()
Bye()
```

It returns "Global name "good" is not defined"

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the variable `good` to be available to other functions without having to run the function `Hello`, you should declare good as a global variable.

```
def Hello():
    global good
    good = 'Nice'
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a quite big code that didn't work because of that, but now it totally works!!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about scopes. The variable `good` exists only within the scope of the function `Hello` - outside this function the variable is not known.

In your case, you should store the return value of `Hello` in a variable - and then pass this variable to the function `Bye`:

```
def Hello():
    good = "Nice"
    return good

def Bye(g):
    print (g)

g = Hello()
Bye(g)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name.
>
> [...]
>
> When a name is not found at all, a NameError exception is raised. If the current scope is a function scope, and the name refers to a local variable that has not yet been bound to a value at the point where the name is used, an UnboundLocalError exception is raised. UnboundLocalError is a subclass of NameError.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution that follows more closely the original code:

```
def Hello():
    good = "Nice"
    return good

def Bye():
    print (good)

good = Hello()
Bye()
```

Python keeps variables defined in a local scope local, therefore you cannot read `good` outside of your function unless you explicitly return it (and store it). Python also doesn't allow you to write to variables defined in a larger scope unless you pass them as an input argument or use the `global` directive. But the OP didn't ask to write to good from within another function. Python DOES allow to read variables from a larger scope. So all you need to do is to store the variable `good` in your larger scope, it is been returned already by the OP's `Hello` function anyway.